# How Would I Perform the ADF Unit Root Test Manually?

Tags: unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller

I am trying to gain a better understanding of the procedure of the ADF unit root test as I believe I am misunderstanding it. I have written python code that follows the steps below and I receive a different test statistic to that of python's "adfuller" function when not accounting for a constant or trend.

Suppose I wanted to perform the ADF test with 3 lags (for simplicity), as I currently understand it:

- Step 1

Construct the equation with 3 lags:

$y_t = \beta_1y_{t-1}+\beta_2y_{t-2}+\beta_3y_{t-3}+\epsilon_t$

Compute the estimated regression:

$y_t = \hat\beta_1y_{t-1}+\hat \beta_2y_{t-2}+\hat \beta_3y_{t-3}$

To obtain the $\hat \beta$'s:

$\hat\beta$ $=$$(X^{'}X)^{-1}X^{'}y_t$

- Step 2

Rewrite the above estimated regression equation to construct the ADF equation:

$\Delta y_t = \hat \pi_1y_{t-1}+\hat c_1\Delta y_{t-1}+\hat c_2\Delta y_{t-2}$

Where the ADF test statistic is $TS=\frac{\hat \pi}{SE(\hat \pi)}$

Where $\hat \pi =\hat\beta_1+\hat\beta_2+\hat\beta_3-1$

[ADF Derivation & TS Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4TBZnrUDrog]

Where $SE(\hat \pi)=\sqrt {MSE}*\sqrt{\Sigma y_{t-1}^2}$

[SE Source: https://www.bauer.uh.edu/rsusmel/phd/ec2-5.pdf] (page 15)

Using an example time series (1 is the newest value, 9 is the oldest value).

I understand this time series would not work as the $X'X$ matrix in the OLS regression would become singular, it is just for easy demonstration:

$$
y_t = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
$$
$$
y_t(adjusted) = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
$$
$$
y_{t-1} = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
$$
$$
y_{t-2} = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
$$
$$
y_{t-3} = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
$$

$$
X=\begin{bmatrix}2&3&4\\3&4&5\\4&5&6\\5&6&7\\6&7&8\\7&8&9\end{bmatrix}X^{'}=\begin{bmatrix}2&3&4&5&6&7\\3&4&5&6&7&8\\4&5&6&7&8&9\end{bmatrix}
$$

I would like to know whether my understanding of the ADF test is wrong or I have simply coded my python script incorrectly. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Your $\hat \pi$ is correct but $SE(\hat \pi)$ not. The way you're computing $\hat \pi$ is also long-winded. The ADF regression is simply $\Delta y_t$ regressed on $y_{t-1}$ and lagged $\Delta$'s. Try running this regression and simply take the t-stat for the coefficient of $y_{t-1}$  .

Comment: I see thank you so much Michael! Could you point me in the direction of the correct calculation for $SE(\hat \pi)$?

Comment: If you run the ADF regression as specified in the previous comment, then it's just the s.e. for the coefficient of $y_{t-1}$. The s.e. would change, of course, depending on how many lags of $\Delta y_t$ is included.